# how to import a 'zip' file to my .py 

Tags: python, import, zip

when i use http://github.com/joshthecoder/tweepy-examples ,

i find :

```
import tweepy
```

in the appengine\oauth_example\handlers.py

but i can't find a tweepy file or tweepy's 'py' file, except a tweepy.zip  file,

i don't think this is right,cauz i never import a zip file,

i find this in app.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'tweepy.zip')
```

why ?

how to import a zip file..

thanks

**updated**

a.py :

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'b.zip')

import b
print b
```

b.zip:

```
b file
   |-----__init__.py
   |-----c.py
```

c.py:

```
cc='ccccc'
```

the error is :

```
> "D:\Python25\pythonw.exe"  "D:\zjm_code\a.py" 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\zjm_code\a.py", line 9, in <module>
    import b
ImportError: No module named b
```

**updated2**

it is ok now ,

the error's reason is : i rename b.rar to b.zip

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The name of the zip file is irrelevent when searching for modules - this allows you to include version numbers in the file name, such as `my_b_package.1.2.3.zip`.

To import from a zip file, you need to replicate the full package structure within it. In this case, you need a package `b`, with the `__init__.py` and `c.py` modules.

I.e:

```
b.zip
|
| -- b <dir>
     | -- __init__.py
     | -- c.py
```

Comment: This helped me greatly with import errors while running AWS Glue jobs.  The messaging is incredibly vague, but tweaking the zip structure to match this answer was the necessary fix.  Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to import from a zip file without adding the zip file to sys.path?

Answer (score 4):

You don't import zip files, you add them to `sys.path` so that you can import modules within them. `sys.path` is a list, and as such the normal list methods/operations (e.g. `.append()`) all work on it.

Comment: but i can't import modules within them,  why ?

Comment: You can import zipped files independently. For example I have a zipped file , with extension `.pyc`, containing `__main__.py` and all the rest of my code. I can then use it as a self contained runnable module but also import it using `zipimport` if I want other entry points.

Comment: Is it possible to import from a zip file without adding the zip file to sys.path?